# Find $F_u(1, 1)$ and $F_{u,v}(1, 1)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Need help on this..
Suppose that $F(u, v) = f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$, where $f$ is a function satisfying 
\begin{cases}f(1, 2) = 3\\f_x(1, 2) = 1\\f_y(1, 2) = −2\\f_{x,x}(1, 2) = 3\\f_{x,y}(1, 2) = 2\\f_{y,y}(1, 2) = 0\end{cases}

Suppose further that $x(u, v) = u + v − 1$ and $y(u, v) = 3uv − 1$. Find $F_u(1, 1)$ and $F_{u,v}(1, 1)$.

I found $F_u(1,1)$ but cannot figure out $F_{u,v}(1 , 1)$. The answer sheet says $F_{u,v}(1 , 1)$ is 9 but I keep turning up 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule,
$$F_u = f_x x_u + f_y y_u $$

Then, using the product rule,

\begin{align} 
  F_{u,v} &= (f_x x_u)_v + (f_y y_u)_v \\
          &=  (f_x)_v x_u + f_x (x_u)_v + (f_y)_v y_u + f_y (y_u)_v
\end{align}

Note that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are still functions of $x$ and $y$.  At $u = v = 1$,

\begin{align}
 (f_x)_v &= f_{xx} x_v + f_{xy} y_v = 3 \cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 3 = 9 \\
 x_u &= 1 \\
  (x_u)_v &= 0 \\
(f_y)_v &= f_{xy} x_v + f_{yy} y_v = 2 \cdot 1 + 0 = 2 \\
y_u &= 3 \\
f_y &= -2 \\
y_{uv} &= 3
\end{align}

Plugging this all back in gives $F_{uv} = 9 \cdot 1 + 0 + 2 \cdot 3 + (-2) \cdot 3 = 9$